# How do I get the type of the depender when registering components with the UsingFactoryMethod() of Castle?

Tags: castle-windsor, factory-method

I'm struggling a bit with getting my bindings correct for my Castle Windsor container. The original problem concerns log4net and named loggers and a description can be found in this question: [Setting the name of a log4net logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783473/setting-the-name-of-a-log4net-logger).

However, the issue is now narrowed down to this:

I have a class Log4NetAuditor which implements IAuditor. Some of my classes extend my abstract class AuditableComponent which has an property Auditor of type IAuditor. When I regiser IAuditor with Castle it knows how to resolve and set the Auditor for all my classes that extend AuditableComponent.

Now, I need the constructor of Log4NetAuditor to take a Type parameter. This type should be the type of the class extending AuditableComponent. I have tried to make this happen through a factory method, but I cannot work it out:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IAuditor>().ImplementedBy<Log4NetAuditor>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(RegisterAuditor).LifeStyle.Transient);

private static IAuditor RegisterAuditor(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model, CreationContext context)
{
    Type loggerType = //magic to find correct type happens here

    return new Log4NetAuditor(loggerType, kernel.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>());
}
```

I'm staring myself blind at this problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha - I just came across my age-old question, so I thought I'd post the answer. The answer is taken from this question: [Why have named logger in Log4Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388482/log4net-logger-why-have-named-logger/13388644#13388644)

The key is to use the CreationContext in the factory method like so

```
...UsingFactoryMethod((kernel,context) => new MyInstance(context.Handler.ComponentModel.Implementation));
```

Of course - add your lifestyle as required.

Answer (score 1):

Castle provides Interceptors which are a good way to configure logging for your application. See this question [Castle, AOP and Logging in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238755/castle-aop-and-logging-in-net)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of Interceptors, but they don't provide the answer to my requirements, particularly as they only work with virtual methods. Thanks for the suggestion, though.